# message.content is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot. In my `message` event, I'm using `message.content.toLowerCase()` to compare the message text to another string. However, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: message.content.toLowerCase is not a function
```

I also tried `message.content`, and that gave me:

```
TypeError: message.content is not a function
```

My code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content('ping')) {
  message.send('pong');
 }
});
```

Comment: and, all the other command also stopèd working with the same error

Comment: Try to log `message` in the event and see what comes up

Comment: how?, sorry im new on all of this

Comment: I'd highly recommend learning Javascript first before anything

Comment: :((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

Comment: It **isn't** a function... It's a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) property. Please read the documentations or try researching on it before asking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message.content` is not a function. `content` is a *property* of the `message` object, which returns the text within the message. I believe you are looking for the `===` operator.

```js
if(message.content === 'ping')
```

Please read [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) to learn about comparison and logical operators.